# CodeIgniter: How can I display single validation error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I used this

```
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
```

the result is

```
Username field is required
Password field is required
<textbox for username>
<textbox for password>
```

what I actually need is to display those errors inline with their element

example:

```
<textbox for username> Username field is required
<textbox for password> Password field is required
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to display error individually you should use the function **form_error('username')**. And for you to get a value of a field being checked, use the function **set_value('username')**.

For these two functions to work, you would have had to, in your controller, set a rule for the 'username' field. Where you specify wich validation rules apply to that field.

```
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>">
```

Here is a [simple tutorial about form Login](http://jrtashjian.com/2009/02/simple-login-form-with-codeigniter-2/)

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the user guide:

> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors
>
> #### Showing Errors Individually
>
> If you prefer to show an error message next to each form field, rather
>   than as a list, you can use the `form_error()` function.

So if your field name is `username`, you would use `form_error('username')`.

> **Important Note**: If you use an array as the name of a form field, you
>   must supply it as an array to the function. Example:
>   `<?php echo form_error('options[size]'); ?>`

This is a shortcut for `$this->form_validation->error()`, which you can also use if you desire.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a different kind of answer when I searched for this question. So I'd like to share my solution to the problem I was having which was "How can I display a single validation error?"

The solution is to run the validation routine before each subsequent form validation rule. That way only the first error is reported.

```
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_check_username');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'callback_check_password');
        }
```